# Cursor within a Procedure Errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

Created a procedure that will take in the service name then print all relevant information with the service name from the reservation table.

```
Set serveroutput ON;
Create or replace procedure Service_Report (service_name_par IN varchar2) 
As --creates a report and takes in one input
Cursor service_cursor IS Select reservation_id, event_place_id, event_type, 
reservation_status, numb_people_attend, event_start_date, event_end_date
from reservation
where service_type_id = service_id;

service_id      services.service_type_id%type;
service_info    service_cursor%rowtype;  

BEGIN
SELECT service_type_id INTO service_id from services
WHERE service_name = service_name_par;
FOR service_info IN service_cursor
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(service_cursor.reservation_id || ‘   ‘ || service_info.event_place_id || ‘   ‘ || service_info.event_type
|| ‘   ‘ || service_info.reservation_status || ‘   ‘ || service_info.numb_people_attend || ‘   ‘ || service_info.event_start_date
|| ‘   ‘ || service_info.event_end_date);
END LOOP;

Exception 
When no_data_found then 
dbms_output.put_line(‘No services found.’); 
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two major problems:

- fancy single quotes you used in DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE call (usually happens when you write queries in e.g. Microsoft Word and copy them into a client you use to access an Oracle database) (note line #21)
- variable - which is used in cursor - has to be declared before the cursor (line #6)

Tables first (only a few columns):

```
SQL> create table reservation
  2    (reservation_id number,
  3     service_type_id number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table services
  2    (service_type_id number,
  3     service_name varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into reservation values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into services values (100, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure service_report(
  2    service_name_par in   varchar2
  3  )
  4  as
  5    --creates a report and takes in one input
  6    service_id     services.service_type_id%type;
  7
  8    cursor service_cursor is
  9      select reservation_id
 10      from reservation
 11      where service_type_id = service_id;
 12
 13    service_info   service_cursor%rowtype;
 14  begin
 15    select service_type_id
 16        into service_id
 17        from services
 18        where service_name = service_name_par;
 19
 20    for service_info in service_cursor loop
 21      dbms_output.put_line( service_info.reservation_id || ' ' || service_id);
 22    end loop;
 23
 24  exception
 25    when no_data_found then
 26      dbms_output.put_line('no services found.');
 27  end;
 28  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec service_report ('Littlefoot');
1 100

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```